# Import Data from Text to ORACLE

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl

**My Computer Configuration:** 1 CPU Intel Xeon 3.07Ghz, 4GB RAM

I import data from local text file **(size=231Mb,1 200 000 rows**) to Oracle Express edition installed on local machine.

I generate SSIS-package through tool "SQL Server Import and Export Data Wizard"

**Package:** **Source:** Text File **Destination:** OLE DB table Oracle

**Screenshot of package**: http://postimg.org/image/nqz33h7lv/

Time of copying is very slow. 23000 rows per minute (75KB/sec).

How I can improve copy speed in SSIS-Package?
I know that the sqlldr is faster, but I want to reach fast speed through OLE DB provider or any other provider in SSIS Package.

Comment: I would recommend using a PL/SQL block with UTL_DIR to read the data from the file, if you are looking for speed using the SSIS-package is a major bottleneck in your architecture.

Comment: If you have a SQL Server enterprise license you can use the Oracle Attunity connectors for SSIS which is a very big improvement over Ole DB.  Question, do you have to bring every row every time?  Maybe an incremental approach from an index or last modified date could help?

Comment: Yes. I bring every row every time. I have a sort of data that need to full update. Thanks. I will investigate about Oracle Atunnity

Comment: That's it!! Attunity really works considerably faster! Thanks for helping